# Trouble with Python 3 turtle mainloop

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

After the `killed()` function is called, the screen just turns white and does nothing.  I thought that because of the `mainloop()` call, the code would just do everything again, but it doesn't seems so.  Any idea of what I could do to resolve this would be much appreciated. (I've no problem with the images.)  Code:

```
from turtle import *
import os 
import time

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')

hp = 200
gold = 0
def m1():
    os.chdir('C:/Users/Python/Projects/Images')
    wn.register_shape("aaa3.gif")
    wn.register_shape("chest.gif")

    stoneGolem = Turtle()
    stoneGolem.shape("aaa3.gif")
    namewriter = Turtle()
    namewriter.hideturtle()
    namewriter.penup()
    namewriter.color('white')
    namewriter.goto(-130, -250)
    fontname = ('Arial', 30, 'normal')
    namewriter.write("Stone Golem", font=fontname)

    writerhp = Turtle()
    writerhp.hideturtle()
    writerhp.penup()
    writerhp.goto(-300, 250)
    writerhp.color('white')
    fonthp = ('Arial', 12, 'normal')
    writerhp.write("Hp: " + str(hp), font=fonthp)

    writergold = Turtle()
    writergold.hideturtle()
    writergold.penup()
    writergold.goto(-200, 250)
    writergold.color('white')
    fontgold = ('Arial', 12, 'normal')
    writergold.write("Gold: " + str(gold), font=fontgold)


    def killed():
        global gold
        gold = gold + 50
        wn.clear()
        wn.bgcolor('black')
        chest = Turtle()
        chest.shape("chest.gif")
        writer0 = Turtle()
        writer0.hideturtle()
        writer0.penup()
        writer0.goto(-280, 180)
        writer0.color('white')
        font = ('Arial', 30, 'normal')
        writer0.write('Stone Golem slayed! Gold + 50!', font=font)
        time.sleep(3)
        wn.clear()



    def clickhp():
        global hp
        if hp > 1:
            hp = hp - 1
            writerhp.clear()
            fonthp = ('Arial', 12, 'normal')
            writerhp.write("Hp: " + str(hp), font=fonthp)
        else:
            killed()
            hp = 200

    wn.onkey(clickhp, 'Up')
    wn.listen()


m1()
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your call to `wn.clear()` in `killed()`.  The turtle documentation is confusing on this point but the definition of invoking `.clear()` on the screen singleton is:

> Delete all drawings and all turtles from the TurtleScreen. Reset the
>   now empty TurtleScreen to its initial state: white background, no
>   background image, no event bindings and tracing on.

Which is why your screen "just turns white and do nothing".  Look for a more appropriate method to clean up your game before your next play.

My rework of your code extract that tries to make it work a little more as you might have intended:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
# import os
import time

FONT_NAME = ('Arial', 30, 'normal')
FONT_HP = ('Arial', 12, 'normal')
FONT_GOLD = ('Arial', 12, 'normal')

def killed():
    global gold

    gold += 50

    writergold.undo()
    writergold.write('Gold: ' + str(gold), font=FONT_GOLD)

    # chest = Turtle('chest.gif')

    writer0.write('Stone Golem slayed! Gold + 50!', font=FONT_NAME)

    time.sleep(3)

    writer0.undo()

def clickhp():
    global hp

    if hp > 1:
        hp -= 1
    else:
        killed()
        hp = 200

    writerhp.undo()
    writerhp.write('Hp: ' + str(hp), font=FONT_HP)

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')

hp = 200
gold = 0

# os.chdir('C:/Users/Python/Projects/Images')
# wn.register_shape('aaa3.gif')
# wn.register_shape('chest.gif')

# stoneGolem = Turtle('aaa3.gif')

namewriter = Turtle(visible=False)
namewriter.penup()
namewriter.color('white')
namewriter.goto(-130, -250)
namewriter.write('Stone Golem', font=FONT_NAME)

writerhp = Turtle(visible=False)
writerhp.penup()
writerhp.color('white')
writerhp.goto(-300, 250)
writerhp.write('Hp: ' + str(hp), font=FONT_HP)

writergold = Turtle(visible=False)
writergold.penup()
writergold.color('white')
writergold.goto(-200, 250)
writergold.write('Gold: ' + str(gold), font=FONT_GOLD)

writer0 = Turtle(visible=False)
writer0.penup()
writer0.color('white')
writer0.goto(-280, 180)

wn.onkey(clickhp, 'Up')
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```